# Find file creator in vb?

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to get the creator of a file using vb8? Can't seem to find anything that will work. I need to find the creator of each file in a directory of hundreds of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this to get the file owner

```
Dim fs As FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl("someFileName.ext")
Dim sid As IdentityReference = fs.GetOwner(GetType(SecurityIdentifier))
Dim ntaccount As IdentityReference = sid.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
Dim owner As String = ntaccount.ToString()
```

Comment: That worked great... But I just discovered that somehow all the files have the same author. Checked file properties and found out that the name I need is actually "last saved by". Is it possible to get that?

Comment: @Erika  I know of a "last modified date" field but nothing about a "last saved by". Can you elaborate and/or provide reference to what it is?

Comment: Once the files are in this folder, they are static. I need to see the last person to write & save the document aka LAST author. Does that make sense?

Comment: Does Windows even maintain that data?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but should help anyone else looking for this info.

Using the [WindowsAPICodePack Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it) packages the file creator/ last modified by information can be easily obtained.

```
Dim sf As Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.ShellFile

Dim authors As String = sf.Properties.GetProperty("System.Author").FormatForDisplay(PropertySystem.PropertyDescriptionFormatOptions.None)

Dim lastModifiedBy As String = sf.Properties.GetProperty("System.Document.LastAuthor").FormatForDisplay(PropertySystem.PropertyDescriptionFormatOptions.None)
```

More info on Windows Property System can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521735(v=vs.85).aspx).